# Mesos slave not seen from web ui

Tags: ansible, mesos, mesosphere

I’m building an Ansible recipe to deploy a mesos/marathon cluster (https://github.com/gridpocket/ansible-mesos-cluster).

Once everything is setup, the mesos and marathon ui are up but I have 2 problems:
  - from the mesos ui I cannot see any slave registered
  - the same ui also indicates "No master is currently leading..."

The setup is the following one:
- 3 mesos master (192.168.1.191, 192, 193): each running mesos-master, zookeeper, marathon
- 3 mesos slaves (192.168.1.194, 195, 196): each running mesos-slave, docker

## Slaves configuration

In each slave:

```
/etc/mesos/zk:    
zk://192.168.1.191:2181,192.168.1.192:2181,192.168.1.193:2181/mesos
```

## Masters configuration

On Each master:

```
/etc/mesos/zk: 
zk://192.168.1.191:2181,192.168.1.192:2181,192.168.1.193:2181/mesos

/etc/mesos-master/quorum:      
2

/etc/mesos-master/hostname and /etc/mesos-master/ip
IP_OF_THE_MASTER
```

Am I missing something in the configuration ?

**EDIT**

I rebuilt the whole cluster and corrected a zookeeper configuration (dataDir). Now,
  - mesos master interface is working and indicates the master node
  - marathon ui is working

On a slave machine, the mesos-slave process stops as soon as I start it.

The mesos-slave log is not very verbose about this problem:

```
Log file created at: 2015/07/09 15:51:15
Running on machine: vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0709 15:51:15.487542  8133 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I0709 15:51:15.488011  8133 main.cpp:156] Build: 2015-05-05 06:15:50 by root
I0709 15:51:15.488081  8133 main.cpp:158] Version: 0.22.1
I0709 15:51:15.488137  8133 main.cpp:161] Git tag: 0.22.1
I0709 15:51:15.488190  8133 main.cpp:165] Git SHA: d6309f92a7f9af3ab61a878403e3d9c284ea87e0
```

**EDIT 2**

When I start a slave manually, indicating the zk string, the slave starts correctly:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --master=zk://192.168.1.191:2181,192.168.1.192:2181,192.168.1.193:2181/mesos
```

But the "sudo service mesos-slave start" does not enable to start the slave.

**EDIT 3**

I've changed the state from "latest" to "present" in the ansible playbook:

```
- name: install mesos + zookeeper
  apt: name=mesos state=present

- name: install marathon
  apt: name=marathon state=present
```

It is fine now, the slaves appears in the activated state in the mesos UI.

Was it due to a version problem ?

Comment: Mind sharing a master log?

Comment: The problem with the "No master is currently leading..." error message seems to be solved now (zookeeper configuration problem). I've updated the question with the slave log as the mesos-slaves process cannot be started.

Comment: To get more verbose logs, start the slave with GLOG_v=1 (or even 2). You can prefix this to your command like `GLOG_v=1 ./bin/mesos-slave --master=[...]` or add it under /etc/default/mesos-slave/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The slaves can be seen as activated within the mesos UI when I used the "present" state instead of the "latest" state in the Ansible playbook while installing mesos.

```
- name: install mesos + zookeeper
  apt: name=mesos state=present

- name: install marathon
  apt: name=marathon state=present
```

Answer (score 2):

Any of the Mesos command-line parameters can be set as files like `/etc/mesos-slave/master` (for `mesos-slave --master`). This is how the service startup finds Mesos parameters.

You can also use `/etc/default/mesos-slave/` (or `-master/`) for environment variables, or `/etc/mesos/` for general parameters.

Comment: I've ran the slave with: "sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --master=zk://192.168.1.191:2181,192.168.1.192:2181,192.168.1.193:2181/mesos", it seems to run fine except that it appears as "deactivated" in the mesos console, then it's not possible to deploy a task through marathon. I've just tested with a /etc/mesos-slave/master (containing the same master string as above) but "sudo service mesos-slave start" does not work either.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "does not work". Provide logs (or gist links) so we can help you debug. And the slave showing up deactivated in the mesos console is not "fine", as it means that there was a problem with the slave connecting/registering with the master, which would mean that there are no resources on which Marathon could run a task.

Comment: Adam, the part where the slave where not seen by the master seems fine (a real "fine" this time) as they appear in the astivated state within the mesos-master UI. When creating a task (sleepalittle: sleep 30) from Marathon UI, it remains in the "deploying" stage. The marathon log file does not really help (http://pastie.org/private/pp7wtjoiwvic7a1tkrdgtq)

Comment: From the Marathon log, I don't see it getting any resource offers. Can you check the Mesos UI to see if it thinks that Marathon is registered? Maybe check the mesos-master log to see if it's sending offers to Marathon's frameworkId.

Comment: From the mesos ui, marathon framework is registerer. I've redeployed the cluster several times and the last time it worked perfectly (when the master was on the first IP in the list). I did not change the Ansible recipe though so I redeploy the whole thing once again, this time the master was the 3rd one in the list and the deployment was not working... The mesos-master node in this last case: http://pastie.org/10288558

Comment: Adam I managed to identify the problem more clearly. I have 3 mesos-masters (192.168.1.191, 192.168.1.192, 192.168.1.193). When the cluster is up, it works perfectly fine (task can be created in the marathon UI) only when if the first server is the mesos-master. Sometimes, when the cluster is created, the mesos-master is not the first server in the list. In that last case the deployment is not possible. Any config file I need to double check ?